# How to unzip a zip file from the Terminal?

Tags: command-line, zip

Just downloaded a .zip file from the internet. I want to use the terminal to unzip the file. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Extract all files from current folder, you can use: unzip \\*.zip

Comment: @burtsevyg the backslash is not necessary there. It will make shell treat `\*` as literal star symbol. Just use `unzip *.zip` to make shell expand `*` to all files ending in `.zip`

Comment: Using `*` alone didn't work for me. It caused `filename not matched` errors. `\*` did the job.

Comment: I recommend you use & learn "unar" instead of a zip specific one, unless you need specific features. "Supported file formats include Zip, Tar-GZip, Tar-BZip2, RAR, 7-zip, LhA, StuffIt and many other old and obscure formats. ".

Comment: Ubuntu has multiple compress/decompress tools already installed.  Run `apropos zip` from the console for the full list.

Comment: Related (for `*.tgz` files): [How to unzip .tgz file using the terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/499807/how-to-unzip-tgz-file-using-the-terminal)

Comment: what about apples unix?

Comment: @CharlieParker ? Apples?

Answer (score 2909, accepted):

If the `unzip` command isn't already installed on your system (use `which unzip` to check), then run:

```
sudo apt-get install unzip
```

After installing the unzip utility, if you want to extract to a particular destination folder, you can use:

```
unzip file.zip -d destination_folder
```

If you want to extract to a directory with the same name as the zip in your current working directory, you can simply do:

```
unzip file.zip
```

Comment: If you are already in the directory you want the file unzipped, omit the 2nd and 3rd arguments, i.e. `unzip /path/to/file.zip`

Comment: I have just used this command. This is an example. Step 1 (I changed to the directory where the zip file is stored): `cd /home/paf/Copy/Programming/Javascript/Json`    Step2 (I extract the zip file in the directory I have just mentioned): `unzip file.zip -d /home/paf/Copy/Programming/Javascript/Json`

Comment: Is there also a "...and visit that folder in terminal" possibility of some kind?

Comment: Does this `unzip file.zip -d destination_folder` will also give all directory which start with .git and files . as start name ,Because this are hidden in Ubuntu .IF it will not extract them then how i can unzip them all from my zip file.

Comment: `unzip` may be a default program. In other words, you may not need to install it.

Comment: what does -d mean

Comment: @Aevi Check man pages `[-d exdir] An  optional  directory  to which to extract files.`

Comment: Make sure you extract to a directory, unlike tar archives, you may find many people include dozens of files in their root directory of their zip files, this can make a real mess!!!

Comment: How to do recursive unzip?, i.e., inside I have one more zip

Comment: unzip is installed by default in (ubuntu) desktop, but not server and WSL. busybox comes with unzip so you don't have to install it; add `alias unzip="busybox unzip"` to "~/.bashrc" (or "~/.zshrc" if zsh is used), then relaunch terminal or login/logout.

Answer (score 288):

You can simply use `unzip`.

Install it:

```
apt-get install unzip
```

And use it:

```
cd /path/to/file
unzip file.zip
```

Answer (score 164):

A more useful tool is `7z`, which zips and unzips a range of compression formats, notably `lzma`, usually the protocol offering the highest compression rates.

This command installs `7z`:

```
sudo apt-get install p7zip-full
```

This command lists the contents of the zip:

```
7z l zipfile.zip
```

This command extracts the contents of the zip:

```
7z x zipfile.zip
```

Comment: `7z e` does not keep the directory structure - `7z x` does...

Comment: 13.10 says 7z does not exist. I think it must sudo apt-get install 7zip

Comment: I think the install command should be `sudo apt-get install p7zip` or `sudo apt-get install p7zip-full` You need the full version to get the `7z` command. The full is also the only one who handles zip and other kinds of formats out of the two.

Comment: could you clarify "A more useful tool"? Are you comparing to unzip? Could you provide any examples of features that make 7z more useful, and perhaps in which contexts 7z is preferred?

Comment: For some unzip is more useful: easy to use and its Name to remember.

Comment: @Chris how to extract to a specific location from `7z`?

Comment: @Shy Robbiani easy != useful. 7zip supports a wide array of compression algorithms while unzip if specifically tailored to . There is also dtrx, which extracts pretty much any archive format without having to specify the specifics.

Comment: @KasunSiyambalapitiya Is just pass the path as argument

Comment: This allowed to unzip a file from Windows 10 that `unzip` failed with.

Comment: If you getting an error with unzip like : extra bit in header , then please use 7z. 7z is way too powerful than simple unzip.

Answer (score 73):

#### Using scripting tools: Perl and Python

Many answers here mention tools that require installation, but nobody has mentioned that two of Ubuntu's scripting languages, Perl and Python, already come with all the necessary modules that allow you to unzip a zip archive, which means you don't need to install anything else. Just use either of the two scripts presented below to do the job. They're fairly short and can even be condensed to a one-liner command if we wanted to.

#### Python

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
from zipfile import PyZipFile
for zip_file in sys.argv[1:]:
    pzf = PyZipFile(zip_file)
    pzf.extractall()
```

Usage:

```
./pyunzip.py master.zip
```

or

```
python3 pyunzip.py master.zip
```

#### Perl

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use Archive::Extract;
foreach my $filepath (@ARGV){
    my $archive = Archive::Extract->new( archive => $filepath );
    $archive->extract;
}
```

Usage:

```
./perlunzip master.zip
```

or

```
perl perlunzip.pl master.zip
```

See also

- [script for extracting tar.gz archives](https://askubuntu.com/a/1076825/295286).
- [How do I create a script file for terminal commands?](https://askubuntu.com/q/223691/295286)

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I need. I  don't have root and don't wanna install unzip manually from source. This also can be used with a bash one-liner which mostly will work (assuming no `'''` inside the file name): `unzip(){ python -c "from zipfile import PyZipFile; PyZipFile( '''$1''' ).extractall()"; }`

Comment: Just use ZipFile class, not PyZipFile, the latter have some specific support for compressing Python libraries

Comment: awesome. pretty quick where you don't have unzip and then root permission to install other binaries

Comment: This one line code using perl: ```perl -e "use Archive::Extract;(Archive::Extract->new(archive => 'numpy-1.22.3.zip'))->extract;"```

Comment: Aces - great reminder! `python -m zipfile -e myfile.zip target-dir/`

Answer (score 65):

You can use:

```
unzip file.zip -d somedir
```

to extract to `yourpath/somedir`

If you want to extract to an absolute path, use

```
sudo unzip file.zip -d /somedir
```

Answer (score 36):

If the source and destination directories are the same, you can simply do:

```
unzip filename.zip
```

Comment: On Ubuntu 17.04,  -d require for unknown reason.

Answer (score 29):

I prefer `bsdtar` to `unzip`/`zip`. For extracting, they are pretty similar:

```
bsdtar -x -f /one/two/three/four.zip -C /five
unzip /one/two/three/four.zip -d /five
```

However for zipping, `bsdtar` wins. Say you have this input:

```
/one/two/three/alfa/four.txt
/one/two/three/bravo/four.txt
```

and want this in the zip file:

```
alfa/four.txt
bravo/four.txt
```

This is easy with `bsdtar`:

```
bsdtar -a -c -f four.zip -C /one/two/three alfa bravo
```

zip does not have the `-d` option like unzip, so you have no way to achieve the above unless you `cd` first.

Comment: As much as I'd like to give the win to a foss tool, apparently `bsdtar` doesn't bode well with special characters like at least one in the word `Blóðstokkinn` when uncrompressing. I didn't even check when compressing. What a bummer. :/ `unzip` handled it without problem.

Answer (score 27):

Here is the detailed description of options that I find useful:

```
Command: unzip -[option] zip-path.
               -d an optional directory to which to extract files  
               -l List archive files.
               -P password Use password to decrypt encrypted zipfile entries (if any).
               -t Test archive files with cyclic redundancy check.  
               -u Update the existing files.  
               -z archive comment
```

Comment: Also unzip -o for overwrite

Answer (score 21):

Follow these instructions: http://www.codebind.com/linux-tutorials/unzip-zip-file-using-terminal-linux-ubuntu-linux-mint-debian/

> ### Install unzip
>
> So First of all we need to install unzip on our system if it’s not installed. unzip command is used to extract files from a
> ZIP archive.
>
> Run the following command to install `unzip`
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install unzip
> ```
>
> `unzip` Syntax
>
> ```
> $ unzip [-aCcfjLlnopqtuvy] [-d dir] zipfile
> ```
>
> Now Follow the steps below:
>
> ### UnZip File
>
> **OPTION 1** – If the Zip File is in the same directory/folder in which your terminal is and we want to extract it in the present
> working directory.
>
> Use the following command to achieve the above described scenario
>
> ```
> sudo unzip zip_file_name.zip
> ```
>
> if the zip file is protected with some password, then use the
> following command :
>
> ```
> sudo ubzip -P zip_file_name.zip
> ```
>
> Please make sure you use -P (capital P) not -p because the are
> different options.
>
> **OPTION 2** – If the zip file is not present in the same directory and we want to extract/unzip the file in different directory.
>
> Use the following command to achieve the above described scenario
>
> ```
> sudo unzip path/filename.zip -d another_path_or_same_path
> ```
>
> if we does not use option -d the file will be extracted to present
> working directory.
>
> And if the zip file is password protected we can also use `-P`.
>
> ### use tar Command in Linux / Unix
>
> `tar` is an acronym for Tape Archive. tar command is used to
> Manipulates archives in Linux/Unix. System administrators uses tar
> command frequently to rip a bunch of files or directories into highly
> compressed archive which are called `tarball` or `tar`, `bzip` and
> `gzip` in *Linux/Unix* system.
>
> **tar Syntax**
>
> ```
> tar [OPTION...] [FILE]...
> ```
>
> Or
>
> **tar required Flags**
>
> ```
> tar {-r|-t|-c|-x|-u}
> ```
>
> **tar optional Flags**
>
> ```
> tar {one of the required Flags} [ -d ][-B] [ -F ] [ -E ] [ -i ] [-h ] [ -l ] [ -m ] [ -o ] [ -p ] [ -w] [ -s ] [ -U ] [ -v ]
> [-Number] [-b Blocks] [-f Archive]
> ```
>
> ### Examples
>
> **Create tar Archive File by Compressing an Directory or a Single File**
>
> The terminal command below will create a `.tar` file called
> `sample_dir.tar` with a directory `/home/codebind/sample_dir` or
> `sample_dir` in present working directory.
>
> ```
> ripon@ripon:~$  tar -cvf sample_dir.tar sample_dir
> sample_dir/
> sample_dir/main.cpp
> sample_dir/sample.png
> sample_dir/output
> ripon@ripon:~$ ls
> sample_dir sample_dir.tar
> ```
>
> [image: Screenshot of the terminal showing the commands above]
>
> Here’s what those flags (-cvf) actually mean
>
> `-c, --create`– create a new archive
>
> `-x, --extract, --get`– extract files from an archive
>
> `-f, --file ARCHIVE`– use archive file or device ARCHIVE
>
> **Create `tar.gz` or `tgz` Archive File by Compressing an Directory or a Single File**
>
> The terminal command below will create a `.tar.gz` file called
> `sample_dir.tar.gz` with a directory `/home/codebind/sample_dir` or
> `sample_dir` in present working directory.
>
> Notice that we have added extra flag -z to the command.Here’s what the
> flag -z actually mean
>
> `-z, --gzip, --gunzip --ungzip`– Compress the archive with gzip
>
> ```
> ripon@ripon:~$ tar -cvzf sample_dir.tar.gz sample_dirsample_dir/
> sample_dir/main.cpp
> sample_dir/sample.png
> sample_dir/output
> ripon@ripon:~$ ls
> sample_dir sample_dir.tar.gz
> ```
>
> [image: Screenshot of the terminal showing the commands above]
>
> The command bellow will create a .tgz file. One this to notice is
> tar.gz and tgz both are similar.
>
> ```
> ripon@ripon:~$ tar -cvzf sample_dir.tgz sample_dirsample_dir/
> sample_dir/main.cpp
> sample_dir/sample.png
> sample_dir/output
> ripon@ripon:~$ ls
> sample_dir sample_dir.tgz
> ```
>
> **Compressing Multiple Directories or Files at Once**
>
> Let’s say, For example we want to compress the `sample_dir` directory,
> the `java_test` directory, and the `abc.py` file to a tar file called
> `sample_dir.tar.gz`.
>
> Run the following command to achieve the goal above.
>
> ```
> ripon@ripon:~$ tar -cvzf sample_dir.tar.gz sample_dir java_test abc.py
> sample_dir/
> sample_dir/main.cpp
> sample_dir/sample.png
> sample_dir/output
> java_test/
> java_test/HelloCV.java
> abc.py
> ripon@ripon:~$ ls
> sample_dir java_test abc.py sample_dir.tar.gz
> ```
>
> [image: Screenshot of the terminal showing the commands above]
>
> **Create `.bzip2` Archive File by Compressing an Directory or a Single File**
>
> ```
> ripon@ripon:~$ tar -cjvf sample_dir.tar.bz2 sample_dir
> sample_dir/
> sample_dir/main.cpp
> sample_dir/sample.png
> sample_dir/output
> ripon@ripon:~$
> ```
>
> Notice that we have added extra flag `-f` to the command.Here’s what
> the flag `-f` actually mean
>
> `-f, --file ARCHIVE`– use archive file or device ARCHIVE
>
> [image: Screenshot of the terminal showing the commands above]
>
> **Extract `.tar` Archive File**
>
> We can extract or untar the compressed file using the tar command. The
> command below will extract the contents of `sample_dir.tar` to the
> present directory.
>
> ```
> ripon@ripon:~$ tar -xvf sample_dir.tar
> sample_dir/
> sample_dir/main.cpp
> sample_dir/sample.png
> sample_dir/output
> ripon@ripon:~$
> ```
>
> [image: Screenshot of the terminal showing the commands above]
>
> The following command will extract or untar files in specified
> Directory i.e. `/home/codebind/dir_name` in this case.
>
> ```
> ripon@ripon:~$ tar -xvf sample_dir.tar -C /home/codebind/dir_name
> sample_dir/
> sample_dir/main.cpp
> sample_dir/sample.png
> sample_dir/output
> ripon@ripon:~$
> ```
>
> we have added extra flag `-C` to the command.Here’s what the flag `-C`
> actually mean
>
> `-C, --directory DIR` – change to directory DIR
>
> [image]

Comment: Also, to check if zip/unzip are installed, use `zip -v` and `unzip -v`.  
If installed it will return something like `UnZip 6.00 of 20 April 2009, by Debian. Original by Info-ZIP.` (plus several lines of additional info.  
If not installed, it will say something like `The program 'zip' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: apt install zip`.