# How to unzip .tgz file using the terminal?

Tags: command-line, tar

I've downloaded `mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.6.3.tgz` file using windows 7 and kept it on `D:\Amra\Software\Developing Soft` location.

When I right click this .tgz file using Ubuntu  and see property it shows `Location:  /media/towhid/Amra/Software/Developing Soft`. Now how will I unzip this .tgz file using `tar` command from terminal?

Answer (score 512, accepted):

To extract a `.tgz` file with tar you need to use,

```
tar -xvzf /path/to/yourfile.tgz
```

where,

- `x` for extract
- `v` for verbose
- `z` for gnuzip
- `f` for file, should come at last just before file name.

You can use the following command in a terminal to unzip the file in your case,

```
tar -xvzf /media/towhid/Amra/Software/Developing\ Soft/mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.6.3.tgz
```

---

#### Extract a `.tgz` file in different directory:

One can use `-C` option to extract archive contents to a different directory as following,

```
tar -xvzf /path/to/yourfile.tgz -C /path/where/to/extract/
```

Comment: It shows following error: `tar (child): /media/towhid/Amra/Software/Developing: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
`

Comment: you just copy my command, there is a syntax error with white space in your command.

Comment: if a folder name is `some folder`, you need to access it from a terminal as `some\ folder` using escape character.

Comment: This is very clear answer where answerer give complete explanation in every option. And a plus given for the example. Very understandable.

Comment: @souravc how we specify the location for the uncompressed files ?

Comment: @KasunSiyambalapitiya you can change directory using `-C` option as `tar -xvzf /path/to/myarchive.tgz -C /path/where/to/extract/`

Comment: you can skip the `- ` whlie specifying the options and do `tar xvzf /path/to/yourFile.tgz`, otherwise it can have unexpected behavior depending on the order of the flags.

check this answer : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/239118/does-parameter-order-matter-with-tar

Answer (score 34):

Let's end the decades of hardly-memorable one-letter tar options. Use this to extract your `.tgz` file:

```
tar --extract --file /path/to/file.tgz
```

The explanation of used options was purposedly left out.

Comment: Great add also the option to [extract files contained in archive.tar.gz to a new directory named archive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59265563/2641825) `tar --extract --file /path/to/file.tgz --one-top-level`. That's often the default of GUI file archive programs.

Comment: I would have upvoted this. Unfortunately, on my old Raspberry Pi at least, this didn't support the Tab autocompletion, and the filename was like 60 chars, whereas `tar -xvzf filename` *did* support Tab autocomplete, so I didn't have to type the whole filename. Therefore, I used the other answer instead.

Comment: @GabrielStaples Well that is strange. I don't have the chance to test it on the Raspberry but the tab completion for this command should definitely work on many linux distributions.

Answer (score 5):

Open the terminal and use the `cd` command to change directories to the directory where the mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.6.3.tgz file is located and the run the following command:

```
tar xzf mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.6.3.tgz
```

The above command will extract the contents of the mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.6.3.tgz archive while preserving the archive's hierarchical tree directory structure.

A similar command extracts .tar.xz files. Open the terminal and the run the following command:

```
tar -xf /path/to/your/file.tar.xz
```

Explanation:

- `-x` extract files from an archive
- `-f` use archive file

Comment: The archive is both compressed (gzip - hence the "z" flag/option), and tar achived, hence the "x" extract option. So unzip won't work since it doesn't do tars.

Comment: Would it not be `tar -xzf`... (with dash)?

Comment: `xzf` with a dash or without a dash, both are OK, and you can also add a v for verbose to the options (`xzvf`) to see the files being extracted during unpacking.