# How do I extract this source tarball?

Tags: source, extract

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What command do I need to unzip/extract a .tar.gz file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25347/what-command-do-i-need-to-unzip-extract-a-tar-gz-file)

I have a source tarball: ap-kernelmodule-1.0.14-13.tar.gz

1. What specific commands should I issue to extract it?
2. What is the default folder/directory of the extracted contents?
3. Can I change the destination folder/directory of the extracted contents?

I am new to Linux and Ubuntu; hence detailed instructions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drag and drop the tar ball to where you want to extract (I keep my windows wide, so I prefer F3) .  Right click and choose extract here.

Comment: Thanks. Under Ubuntu 12.10, is there a default destination/target folder/directory of extracted contents?

Comment: No, that is controlled by the (usually) saved sub-directory structure in the compressed file.  When you extract a tar ball it will be created in the current directory, but with the same subdirectories as those used to create it.

Comment: @ fabricator4: Thanks a lot. A Merry Christmas to you and your loved ones.