# Ways to unpackage a tar file

Tags: package-management, tar

I have heard of many different ways to unpackage a .tar file but it is unclear which ones are "official" (if there is one) and how they are different.

Also, I have noticed that some work on some files but not others.

Can someone explain the difference between different commands and file types (.tar.bz2, .tar.gz...)?

Comment: tar.gz: http://askubuntu.com/questions/25347/what-command-do-i-need-to-unzip-extract-a-tar-gz-file/25348#25348, tar.xz: http://askubuntu.com/q/92328/178596. tar.bz2 (probably): `tar -xvjf FILE.tar.bz2`. Lots of other existing similar questions can be found using the search bar.

Comment: Right-click and select 'Extract Here.'