# Problem extracting tar.gz files: You must specify one of the '-Acdtrux', '--delete' or '--test-label' options

Tags: command-line, tar, extract

Recently I encountered a problem while trying to install Quantum Espresso 5.2.0, a  Linux-based software, in Ubuntu 14.04. The source was a compressed tar.gz file. I typed the following command to extract the files contained in it :

```
tar - zxvf espresso-5.2.0.tar.gz
```

But the Terminal showed the following message :

```
tar: You must specify one of the '-Acdtrux', '--delete' or '--test-label' options
Try 'tar --help' or 'tar --usage' for more information.
```

I followed the suggestions but couldn’t solve the problem. Could anybody help me with this?

Comment: Try `tar -zxvf espresso-5.2.0.tar.gz`, note, no space between - and zxvf.

Comment: your problem solved??

Answer (score 8):

Use `man tar` for more information, the command should be like this :

```
tar -zxvf espresso-5.2.0.tar.gz
```

No space between `-` and `zxvf`

For more [details](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25347/what-command-do-i-need-to-unzip-extract-a-tar-gz-file).