# How to uncompress VMware tools file with tar

Tags: vmware-tools

I'm attempting to install VMware tools on a Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS vm and I get the following message:

> Make sure that you are logged in to the guest OS. Mount the virtual cd drive in the guest, launch a terminal, and use tar to uncompress the installer. Then, execute vmware-install.pl to install VMware tools.

What does it mean, "use tar to uncompress the installer"?

Comment: Please include what research you have done to solve this issue. Simply googling the phrase "use tar to uncompress the installer" leads to this page: https://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_newguest_tools_linux.html

Comment: Almost certainly a duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/25347/what-command-do-i-need-to-unzip-extract-a-tar-gz-file

Answer (score 2):

`tar` is a program to produce (and unzip) archives from multiple files, and also a file format just like `.rar` or `.zip` commonly seen in Windows.

What the program is asking you to do is follow the steps and then unzip the `.tar` file you get.

To unzip the `.tar` file use this `tar xvzf <nameoffilehere>.tar.gz`

**A bit more explanation of what the command does:**

- `f`: this must be the last flag of the command, and the tar file must be immediately after. It tells tar the name and path of the compressed file.
- `z`: tells tar to decompress the archive using gzip
- `x`: tar can collect files or extract them. x does the latter.
- `v`: makes tar talk a lot. Verbose output shows you all the files being extracted.