# extract and save subfiles from a gz file

Tags: files, extract, gzip

**EDIT: I used the command tar xvfz and everything is good now. I see a subfolder with all the files in it, just as i wanted to.**

First, please excuse me this is a stupid question, i am very new to this operating system and i still find it quite difficult. I have i GZ file with some files in it - examples with c/c++ code. My question is how can i "uznip" this file in a new folder, so i can have easy access to all the files in it. I tried using gzip and gunzip (although the only thing i understood was probably that gunzip is the opposite of gzip), but i did not achieve anything. I didn't get any errors, the commands are working properly, but i do not know how to extract all the files in a folder of my choice. Some help please?

Comment: what do you mean you didn't achieve anything? What were you left with after gunzipping?

Comment: Do you mean tar.gz ? if so look at this https://askubuntu.com/a/25348/458673

Comment: i wrote the command, could not see anything happen in the terminal. I assume something is happening in the background, but i cant figure out how to put the subfiles in a folder. If i do gunzip i no longer see the file name in red - thus the file is "unzipped". If i then use gzip - i see the fie name in red again, so the commands are working. But basically i don't understand what is happening and where i can search for my files. Hope i got it clear, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: If it has file**s** (plural) in it, then it's probably a gzipped `tar` archive, and you should use `tar` rather than `gzip` directly (using `gzip` will just result in a single de-compressed tarfile that still needs to be unpacked to get at the individual files).

Comment: As the question includes its answer and does not meet the askubuntu format, I vote for it to be closed.